# jquery, get data via ajax then submit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data via ajax then send it through a form. However it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <input id="myvar" type="hidden" name="albumid" />
    <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function() {  
     $.ajax({
            url: "newAlbum.php",
            success: function(data){
            var album = data;
                 $('#myvar').val(album);
             }
          });   

    });
</script>
```

newAlbum.php

```
<?PHP echo '11'; ?>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $_GET["albumid"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay try adding as follows:

```
 $('form').submit(function() {  
       $.ajax({
        url: "newAlbum.php",
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
        var album = data;
             $('#myvar').val(album);
         }
      });   

});
```

Comment: addded the data parameter but it seems the ajax is returning false and not letting me submit the form. All i have on newAlbum.php is echo 11

Comment: can you try giving `return true;` on the success function ?

Comment: same thing. nothing happens when I click on submit, here is my updated code for all 3 pages:

http://pastebin.com/49wczwsG

Comment: Okay try calling the ajax function on page load and then submit the form. check updated code

Comment: yeah that works, but I really need it to grab it once they click submit. The value it's retrieving is updating everytime. So if multiple users are on the page I don't want it to give the same value to both of them.

Comment: I got it working. I added async:false, which prevents form submission until the ajax completes. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

As someone else pointed out - you need to add the `data` parameter. But I would also use `$(this).serialize()`, since that will fetch all form input elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function() {  
        $.ajax({
            url: "newAlbum.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
            var album = data;
                 $('#myvar').val(album);
            },
            error : function(data) {
                console.log(data);   
            }
          });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I addded the data parameter but it seems the ajax is returning false and not letting me submit the form. All i have on newAlbum is echo 11

Comment: I added an error handler and removed `return false;`. Check the console (F12 in Chrome) to see what the error is.

Answer (score -1):

Try receiving the data as JSON

```
$.getJSON()
```